# Eclipse + Maven + Dynamic Web Project -> Maven overwrites Deployment Assembly

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, maven, deployment

**Summary**

In Eclipse, when I "Maven->Update Project Configuration" "Maven Dependencies" gets removed from the "Deployment Assembly" of my project.

**Details**

I started with a pre-configured Eclipse project: File->New->Dynamic Web Project->JavaServer Face v2.0 Project. To remove the "magic" I then converted it to a Maven project: Configure->Convert to Maven project.

pom.xml contains the following:

```
<build>
    <finalName>jsf-facelets-tutorial</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <webXml>WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>myfaces-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Then, to make sure the Maven dependencies are copied to "WEB-INF/lib/" before deploying, 
I added them to the project's "Deployment Assembly": Project Properties->Deployment Assembly. For more details, see this question: [Eclipse + Maven + JavaServer Faces -> ClassNotFoundException: StartupServletContextListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9973599/eclipse-maven-javaserver-faces-classnotfoundexception-startupservletcont).

I know have two related problems.

**Problems**

**(1)** When I "Project->Maven->Update Project Configuration", "Maven Dependencies" gets removed from my "Deployment Assembly". Is there a way to stop this from happening, possibly via some Maven plugin?

**(2)** When I build the .war from within Eclipse everything is fine, the .war runs fine in Tomcat. But when I build it from command line with Maven, `mvn clean compile war:war`, the .html files from "WebContent/" is not added to the .war. Again, Which Maven settings/plugins do I need to remedy this?

FYI, it's a very basic application... just a login page and a welcome page.

If there are any additional details I should provide (web.xml, faces-config-xml, login.xhtml), let me know and I'll add them.

Thanks

**--EDIT--**

Eclipse version: 3.6.2

Eclipse m2e version: 1.0.1

Apache Maven version: 2.2.1

**(1) Solution**

Updated to Eclipse Java EE 3.7.2 (Indigo). Now also using [m2e-wtp Maven Integration for Eclipse WTP plugin](http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/m2eclipse-wtp/)

**(2) Solution**

Created new Maven project from [archetype](http://myfaces.apache.org/build-tools/archetypes/myfaces-archetype-helloworld20/index.html), then Eclipse->Import->Existing Maven Project. With new Eclipse version and the m2e-wtp, the Java EE perspective in Eclipse works well with the standard Maven directory structure

The pom.xml is now simpler too:

```
<build>
    <finalName>jsf-facelets-tutorial</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>myfaces-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Which version of Eclipse and M2Eclipse are you using?

Comment: Eclipse version: 3.6.2
Eclipse m2e version: 1.0.1
Apache Maven version: 2.2.1

Comment: I have updated my answer to address your question regarding the WebContent directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend to move to Eclipse 3.7.x (Indigo), which has better support for *m2e*, and also allows you to use the *Maven Integration for WTP* (separate install), which should make things a lot easier. I guess most of your problems should be solved by updating to Indigo.

Install Link: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/node/96737

Also see here: [Maven/Tomcat Projects In Eclipse Indigo/3.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356421/maven-tomcat-projects-in-eclipse-indigo-3-7)

**Edit**
Putting your web resources under *WebContent* and then adding that as a directory in the WAR plugin may be a solution. The clean way would be to have them under `src/main/resources` or `src/main/webapp` and they should be included automatically in the WAR file. `WebContent` is not one of Maven's standard directories.

Comment: Thanks, will try out and get back to you when I'm done (will take a bit of time to download & install everything, then start new project). One question, with the "m2eclipse-wtp" plugin, will I still need to use build-helper-maven-plugin (Maven plugin) & m2e-build-helper-connector (Eclipse)?

Comment: Installed now. With this new configuration, what method of creating a project do you recommend? command line maven from archetype, or using Eclipse wizard?

Comment: I always create a small basic POM, either by copying from another project, or by using the archetype wizard from within Eclipse.

Comment: with the new structure I know see this... in Web Deployment Assembly I see 4 entries. _((1))_ /src/main/java -> WEB-INF/classes **[OK]** _((2))_ /src/main/webapp -> / **[.html, web.xml, etc.?]** _((3))_ Maven Dependencies -> WEB-INF/lib **[OK]** _((4))_ /target/m2e-wtp/web-resources -> / **[what is this for?]**

Comment: when working on a WTP project with the m2e and m2e-wtp plugins, do the Faces Config Editor still open? Mine no longer does, and I've been unable find out why (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9992977/eclipse-faces-config-editor-not-working)

Comment: I haven't used this editor so far, but a quick test shows that I can open a `faces-config.xml` file fine with it.

Comment: did you just use "Open With..."->"Faces Config Editor"?

Comment: ok it was a dumb mistake. i didn't add JavaServer Faces facet my project because it broke my build, but now I see I just had to remove the Eclipse-added JSF library from my build path... everything fine now

Comment: That "src/main/webapp" hint helped me understand what I was doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: It is a old subject, but i have exactly the same pb with Eclipse Mars. So what to do ? :p