# Maven Dependencies disappears from deployment assembly after Maven update

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, deployment, web-inf

I am making a webapp using maven. The problem is that everytime I do maven update project, the Maven Dependencies library disappears from the deployment assembly to WEB-INF. I have to re-add it manually every time. It is similar to problem 1 in this post: [Eclipse + Maven + Dynamic Web Project -> Maven overwrites Deployment Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9976049/eclipse-maven-dynamic-web-project-maven-overwrites-deployment-assembly#new-answer?newreg=9ef553c066574b02acb3dbed899e2a07)

His solution was to update eclipse, but I am already on newest version (mars) and I have all maven plugins installed properly. I know this because I have another web application built using maven that working completely fine without this issue. I've looked through a bunch of settings and the  two look completely identical, so I cannot figure out why. Is there some place where I can set so the Maven Dependencies are added automatically to the deployment assembly even after maven update project?

Comment: Can you show your pom file? Otherwise it's impossible to say something about it...

Comment: "Is there some place where I can set so the Maven Dependencies are added automatically to the deployment assembly even after maven update project?" - the whole point of m2eclipse is that it does this for you. How did this workspace come to be? Was it freshly created in Eclipse Mars, or was it upgraded from a workspace created in a previous version?